# JQuery Sortable Preview

Tags: jquery-ui

I need help with Sortable JQuery UI. My requirement is whenever I move the 1st div (portlet 1) with 5th div (portlet 5) 5th and 1st should get swapped and before releasing the mouse the preview should be the same (portlet 5 should be in the first place). Please help me. 
Please find the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R_S/3TqTU/2/

```
<div class="dropme">
<div class="rpt 1 row1"><span class="heading">Portlet 1</span></div>
<div class="rpt 2 row1"><span class="heading">Portlet 2</span></div>
<div class="rpt 3 row1"><span class="heading">Portlet 3</span></div>
<div class="rpt 4 row2"><span class="heading">Portlet 4</span></div>
<div class="rpt 5 row2"><span class="heading">Portlet 5</span></div>
<div class="rpt 6 row2"><span class="heading">Portlet 6</span></div>
<div class="rpt 7 row3"><span class="heading">Portlet 7</span></div>
<div class="rpt 8 row3"><span class="heading">Portlet 8</span></div>
<div class="rpt 9 row3"><span class="heading">Portlet 9</span></div>
</div>
$('.rpt').draggable({
cursor: 'pointer',
connectWith: '.rpt',
connectToSortable:'.dropme'
helper: 'clone'

});

$('.dropme').sortable({
connectWith: '.dropme',
cursor: 'pointer' 
});
```